# Get image from camera without pressing ok button after camera click in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I did code for capturing the image from camera and it works fine, 
After capturing the image it is asking for click ok in camera but i want to get image without clicking on ok button. my code for is as below and i don't have idea to get image without clicking ok button so please help me.

```
button_camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Log.e("PATH", filePath+"");
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

On button click listerner write the following code

```
 cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, we should notify the camera intent to enable `quick capture` mode, while calling it. Below the code:

```
private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.quickCapture", true); // enables single click image capture
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

**Note:** I learned from stackoverflow and few other sites people say some devices do not support this mode. And I am not sure what devices those are. To this date, I've tested on devices from different brands with API levels 21 to 28, which all has worked for me so far.